# Is there any way to test the code coverage of UIAutomation tests?

Tags: ios, code-coverage, ios-ui-automation

I am using UIAutomation to test an app, and I would like to find out my code coverage. But since javascript has no preprocessor, that means that gcov and similar are not an option. Has anyone come up with a solution for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Xcode version 4.5 and newer:

1. Set the “Generate Test Coverage Files” build setting to Yes.
2. Set the “Instrument Program Flow” build setting to Yes.

This will generate code coverage files every time you run your application in the simulator and exit the application. A detailed explanation of these two steps can be found at the beginning of http://qualitycoding.org/xcode-code-coverage/.

For any unit tests, code coverage files will be generated every time you hit the test button and the tests complete. For UIAutomation, it is a little bit more tricky. You have to ensure the application exits at the conclusion of your tests. The easiest way I found to do this is to turn off multitasking. Add UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend in your MyAppName-Info.plist file and set this option to 'YES'. Run your UI automation test and at the end of it you can exit the app either by manually pressing the home button in the simulator or using the UIATarget.localTarget().deactivateAppForDuration() method.

Note: if your app has any UI Automation tests that rely on the deactivateAppForDuration() method, the tests will terminate upon running the command.

Answer (score -3):

Code Coverage is only used for Unit Testing, there is no Code Coverage for UIAutomation because there is no way to tell how many elements on screen has been "touched" by UIAutoamtion

Comment: code coverage tells you the percentage of lines in your application that were executed during your tests. You can execute a ui automation test and monitor this as you would for a unit test